# El significado de "si dispones de unos datos bancarios en dichas divisas, no supondrá ningún trámite excepcional..."

Tags: significado

No entiendo el significado de la siguiente oración, especialmente la parte donde dice "con unos datos bancarios locales que podrás disponer en dólares estadounidenses o australianos, euros o libras de Reino Unido". O sea, ¿por qué si dispones de unos datos bancarios en dichas divisas "no supondrá ningún trámite excepcional y lo hará como una transferencia nacional"? La oración parece ser de tipo Spanglish.

> La cuenta multidivisa de TransferWise ... Además, también dispone de la posibilidad de recibir transferencias internacionales en divisas **con unos datos bancarios locales que podrás disponer en dólares estadounidenses o australianos, euros o libras de Reino Unido**. Esto significa que para la persona que envíe esa transferencia no supondrá ningún trámite excepcional y lo hará como una transferencia nacional.

Comment: Votando como off-topic por que esto mas bien parece que busca la interprestacion de terminos bancarios, que a mi parecer Deben de ser evaluados con abogados o personal autorizado para no dar una incorrecta interpretacion del mismo. para seguridad del stack y los usuarios mismos creo que no deberia ser respondida

Comment: Creo que es una mala traducción y nada más, pero para eso deberíamos poder ver el texto original en inglés.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have not provided a link to the paragraph.  To answer your question we would need to be able to look at the context of your quote.

Comment: Eché un ojo al sitio web del servicio.  Se ofrecen varias versiones mulilingües del sitio, pero la versión en español es un desastre.  Por ejemplo: "If you think we should add a specific currency, let us know. Be the first to know when we add more by signing up to our mailing list." -> "Entérate el primero cuando agreguemos más registrándote a nuestra lista de correo." Ay, dios mío.  Mira, recomiendo que copies el texto en inglés y que lo pases por Google Translate.  Los resultados no serán peores que la traducción que hizo TransferWise.